# Channel Form and Grid Images : AJAX

Tags: safecracker, grid, ajax, image

Having an issue where my form is losing all image values on a grid when saving via AJAX. I have the parameters on my channel form as json="yes" include_assets="yes"

Is the issue that I'm sending via Json? Is there a hidden field trick? Anyone have any knowledge or expreience working with grid images in a channel form and updating the entry?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 

    // other available options: 
    //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
    //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
    //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
    //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

    // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
    //timeout:   3000 
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#cform').ajaxForm(options);
```

});